# Make option in a multiply select box extend options available

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysqli

I have 4 tabels in phpmyadmin with the menu there is showed on main page, 1 for MENU, 1 for UNDERMENU, 1 for UNDERMENU2 and 1 for UNDERMENU3. The text from UNDERMENU2 is connected to the MENU id where it belong.

Take this as an example: MENU1 id=1, MENU2 id=2, in tabel MENU. UNDERMENU1 id=1 menu_id=2, UNDERMENU2 id=2 menu_id=1, for tabel UNDERMENU. UNDERMENU2_1 id=1 menu_id=1 undermenu_id=1, UNDERMENU2_2 id=2 menu_id=1 undermenu_id=2...... And so on. Hope you understand me.

Now what i want is that all the MENU's printed in my multiply select box with a + symbol to the left for the text, so the user can hit this + symbol to get all the UNDERMENU's printed below the MENU's + symbol ypu hitted and so on.

Illustration:

[image: Illustration]

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript can't override that kind of default browser behavior. You'll need to build a "fake" select box and then you're free to do whatever you would like. [Here is a good explanation and example of what's involved](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2012/06/20/create-a-custom-select-box-with-jquery/)

Comment: This look quite time consuming, i would think there was some script etc. made by someone on the net that could handle this ?

Comment: @user1824324 Maybe there is but I wouldn't be surprised if there wasn't. Using a select box like this isn't a normal way to display that much information.

Comment: Any other suggestions ?

Comment: You might want to try asking over at [ux.stackexchange](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) not for the technical details but about the best way to present the options. The only thing I can think of is cascading select boxes but that might be kind of awkward to use.